# what is the use of media attribute inside anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML, and while studying some HTML tags, im constantly seeing `media` attribute is supported by some elements other than `link` tag. I know in `<link>` tag you can use `media` attribute to link an html doc to 2 different external css files that have screen size-specific formatting.

But i don't understand the use of `media` attribute inside the `<a>` tag or `<source>` tag. what is the use case of `media` tag in these 2 tags.

When i run the below codes (from w3school website) with or without the `media` attribute, i can't see any difference.

```html
<!-- examples from w3 school -->

<a href="att_a_media.asp?output=print"
media="print and (resolution:300dpi)">
Open media attribute page for print.</a>

<!-- or -->

<source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
```

Is the `media` attribute important for these 2 tags, can i just safely ignore them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`media` is one of available attributes for [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area), [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) and [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tags.

MDN describes `media`:

> This attribute specifies the media that the linked resource applies
> to. Its value must be a media type / [**media query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries). This attribute is
> mainly useful when linking to external stylesheets — it allows the
> user agent to pick the best adapted one for the device it runs on.

> In HTML, **media queries** can be applied to various elements:
>
> - In the [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) element's [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media) attribute, they define the media to    which a linked resource (typically CSS) should be applied.
> - In the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) element's [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-media) attribute, they define the media to    which that source should be applied. (This is only valid inside
>   [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) elements.)
> - In the [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) element's [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-media) attribute, they define the media to    which the style should be applied.

Examples from MDN:

```html
<!-- link tag -->
<link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)">

<!-- picture tag -->
<picture>
   <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 800px)">
   <source srcset="mdn-logo-medium.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
   <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN Web Docs">
</picture>
```

MDN **Notes**:

> In HTML 4, this can only be a simple white-space-separated list of
> media description literals, i.e., [media types and groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), where
> defined and allowed as values for this attribute, such as print,
> screen, aural, braille. HTML5 extended this to any kind of [media
> queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries), which are a superset of the allowed values of HTML 4.
>
> Browsers not supporting [CSS3 Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) won't necessarily recognize
> the adequate link; do not forget to set fallback links, the restricted
> set of media queries defined in HTML 4.

Comment: Now this makes sense. And all this time i was trying to make sense of this sentence from w3school that says - "it specifies what media or device the linked document is optimized for"

Answer (score 1):

it specifies what media or device the linked document is optimized for.This attribute is used to specify that the target URL is designed for special devices (like iPhone), speech or print media.
Only used if the href attribute is present.
and Yes You can Ignore The media Attribute if you dont need it

Comment: but what does it mean. does the linked document will only show in the optimized device (like iphone) ?. or does the linked document will show in every device but browser will know it is optimized for iphone.

Answer (score 1):

It's Specifies the pixel density (dpi) of the target display/paper.
"min-" and "max-" prefixes can be used. You can see the result if you try to print the web page.

```
<a href="att_a_media.asp?output=print"
media="print and (resolution:300dpi)">
Open media attribute page for print.</a>
```

`<source>` is the child of the `<picture>` element most common use of the `<picture>` element will be for art direction in responsive designs. Instead of having one image that is scaled up or down based on the viewport width, multiple images can be designed to fill the browser viewport.

Example:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: alright, this means - `<source>` tag supports `media` attribute because of `<picture>` tag ( to set multiple images ). so, using `media` attribute in  `<source>` tag inside `<video>` or `<audio>` tag is useless. So `media` attribute inside `<a>` tag  maybe is usefull for some similar situation, and didn't meant to be used for when creating some basic hyperlink.

Comment: `media` attribute inside `<a>` tag no need all the time it's based on the need/situation.
`Video` and  `<audio>` elements inside can add multiple `<source>` tags with the different file formats. 

`<video controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>`

`<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`